# Paginating component doesn't need initial query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I want a component to receive its initial data from its parent component, while still being able to paginate data on its own.

For instance, consider

```
<Parent> //Makes initial GraphQL call
  <StaticChild/> //Uses initial data and never needs to rerender
  <DynamicChild/> //Paginates the same query that the Parent made, will need to rerender for every new "page"
</Parent>
```

What would `<DynamicChild>` look like? My understanding is, in order to have access to fetchMore (for pagination), you have to wrap `<DynamicChild>` in the `graphql` function (from react-apollo). But that `graphql` function requires an initial query, which `<DynamicChild>` doesn’t need to make. My options seem to be:

a) Have `<Parent>` handle pagination. This means I'd have to add a shouldComponentUpdate method to `<StaticChild>`.

b) Have `<DynamicChild>` make a similar initial query as `<Parent>`and rely on Apollo pulling the second query from the Redux store (assuming the two queries don't instead get batched together).

c) Have `<Parent>` make the initial query and pass down the fetchMore() callback to `<DynamicChild>`. I fear that when `<DynamicChild>` used the callback, it would still attempt to rerender `<Parent>`.

While these solutions are simple enough, is there a way to have `<DynamicChild>` define its own pagination query without defining its own initial query?

Answer (score 0):

As an example for the refetch functionality you could take a look at the feed page of an app made with GraphQL and apollo client ([feed page](https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React/blob/master/ui/routes/FeedPage.js)).

As of b) i think it will fetch the query twice when entering the page the first time. I have a similar issue and the query is fetched in the parent and the child.

I think you are right in c) that after fetchMore is called it will rerender the parent

Comment: This solution you posted is essentially situation (b). On line 44, the component is given FEED_QUERY as its initial query. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: I think its solution c) the feed page uses the [Feed](https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React/blob/master/ui/components/Feed.js) component which gets the onLoadMore => fetchMore function. From the parent.